# HTML print webpage with different headers

Tags: html, css, printing

I want to print a webpage that will print more than one page.
In the first page i want a header and in the following ones different headers should appear.

The question is that in the first page I have a label that has enough text to pass to the second page, being the header in the second page the same as the first. I want that the second page header be different.

To define the headers i use the following approach:

```
<table>
     <thead>
             (...Header Html Code)           
     </thead>
     <tbody>
            (...Html Code with label with a lot of text)
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define different CSS files for print and view, (there is even an option to define one for braile readers or mobile) 
So you can define some divs with ids of "webonly" "printonly" and hide them by CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/screen.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/print.css" media="print" />
```

Firstly, in the stylesheet for displaying on screen...

```
div#header {
 font-family: verdana;
 margin: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
 font-size: large;
 font-weight: bold;
 background-color: #c0c0c0;
 border: #191170 2px solid;
}
```

...and then in the printable stylesheet

```
div#header {
 font-family: arial;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I know that css feature for print. The question is different headers. I only want that the first page header be different of the following ones.

Comment: If you comment the items with a frontpage id then you can do   for example div#frontheader { diaplay:block; }   and div#frontheaderprint { display:none; }       and you invert that on the print CSS